# Anyway delete unique files with a .bat file, using another folder's content as reference?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to delete files from a "FolderA" using a "FolderB" as a reference w/ a Batch File.

For Example:

| C:\FolderA | C:\FolderB |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | Item1 |
| Item2 | Item2 |
| Item3 |  |

Item3 gets deleted in FolderA due to FolderB not having it

Right now I have a .bat file where it can copy contents from FolderB to FolderA using a simple xcopy line, but if FolderB gets an update where an item gets removed I don't know to go about deleting those items with the same or different .bat file.

Comment: Is Powershell an option or does it have to be a bat file?

Comment: Robocopy can mirror two folders, and is "part of windows." check especially, /MIR and /PURGE (or /E) switches. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && cd/d "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderA\" 

for %%i in (*)do if not exist "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderB\%%~nxi" (
     del/q /f "%%~fi") else copy/y "%%~i" "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderB\%%~nxi"
```

---

**1.** Enter the folder where you want to delete or to copy your files:

```bat
@echo off && cd/d "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderA\"
```

Use a for file inside that folder (FolderA)

**2.** Use a for file inside that folder (.\FolderA) that lists your files:

```bat
for %%i in (*)do...
```

**3.** Implement an if() else () condition to check if the same file not exists in FolderB:

```bat
... if not exist "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderB\%%~nxi" (...
```

**4.** For each condition, operate respectively by deleting or copying the file in a loop:

```bat
 del/q /f "%%~fi") else copy/y "%%~i" "F:\2021-SU\Q1631994\FolderB\%%~nxi"
```

- Some further reading:

  - **[Del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)**
  - **[Echo](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
  - **[Copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
  - **[If condition() else condition()](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much! Especially for the references to read! I couldn't appreciate this reply anymore than I am.

Comment: @Kanon Thank you for test, comment and read ref links!